# Ícone font awesome 5 não aparece ao ser chamado pelo css

Tags: html5, scss, font-awesome

Pessoal estou usando fontawesome 5 e alguns icones não aparecem quando eu chamo eles pelo css segue meu código e print da tela de como o icone está sendo exibido.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-2 offset-lg-2 align-self-center">
    <p class="phone">Ligue para nós<br><span>11 97032-5884</span></p>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.phone{
    position: relative;
    color: $white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
    &:after{
      content: '\f232';
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      position: absolute;
      left: -35px;
      top: 50%;
      font-size: 25px;
      margin-top: -7.5px;
      color: $white;
    }
    span{
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Seu font-family está errado! Vcusou a `Font Awesome 5 Free` mas deveria ser a `Font Awesome 5 Brands`

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
.phone {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.phone:after {
  content: "\f232";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  position: absolute;
  left: -35px;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
  color: white;
}

.phone span {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css">

<div class="col-lg-2 offset-lg-2 align-self-center">
  <p class="phone">Ligue para nós<br><span>11 97032-5884</span></p>
</div>
```

Veja que na própria documentação indica o uso da `Brands Style`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que tem que usar o `Font Awesome 5 Brands`?

Comment: @VictorCarnaval editei a resposta e inclui uma imagem que vai te esclarecer

Comment: É que nunca usei dessa forma o font awesome... Sempre utilizei as classes em elementos de ícone. Além do mais não consegui nem achar a documentação da versão 5.0.10 que você encontrou kkk

Comment: @VictorCarnaval aqui está a documentação de como usar o FA em pseudo-elementos, que nesse caso o indicado é que use o FA.css e não o .JS se não me engano. Agora olhe essas imagens, elas usariam a family-free, e vc ainda tem que ver que uma é para font-wigth 900 e outra para 400, dependendo do preenchimento do ícone http://prntscr.com/nm2aqv

Comment: Você tem alguma sugestão de como posso aprender a utilizar essas fontes da forma como explicou? Confesso que não entendi muito bem ainda.

Comment: @VictorCarnaval olha essa outra imagem http://prntscr.com/nm2c90 acho que vai ficar mis claro pra vc entender. No site do próprio FontAwesome tem um moute de instrução de como trabalhar com a fonte, inclusive como fazer Stack de ícone um sobre o outro e animalos, trocar cor etc. Mas no youtube acredito que devam ter vídeos sobre o assunto

Comment: Obrigado @hugocsl.